# How to pass/ where to store a massive json that is passed in post request

Tags: python, json, rest, automation, pytest

I am automating some APIs.

In some cases, I need to pass massive JSON messages in the POST request as data. Some of these messages are 50-100 lines long and take parameters to be adjusted to each one of the needed environments.
I have a dedicated page for these messages, each test calling the desired JSON and passing the relevant arguments.

Theoretically, I can do the same with all the jsons, however, that does not seem like the best practice to me.

Any ideas, where to store my jsons and still be able to pass them the needed arguments without having to store thousands of lines of code in my project?

Thanks. 
PS - The project is python automation, built with pytest.

Comment: 50-100 lines long isn't that massive (depending on line length of course). You've got to store them somewhere, either in a file or memory.

Answer (score 0):

Storing test data in your project together with tests is reasonable approach. If there are 50-100 lines long json per test, you could think of some way to deduplicate test data.

There are many ways to do it, e.g.:

- collect base json from API and update only what needs to be tested,
- extract common json template(s) and update it per test,
- generate test data from scratch using some setup logic.